# How to store retrieved data from multiple textfields in SQLite database and display that data on 3 screens in flutter?

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter

I have a form in my flutter app in which there are 5 text fields (in which 2 are strings and 3 are integers) and a "submit" button. I want to store that data to my SQLite database and want to display that data on 3 screens. Please help me.

Please Check the code of the Database below. Some methods are remaining to be added, but will add them later.

**Just For Clarification - This will be an Android App**

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import 'models/account_summary_db.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  DatabaseHelper() {
    database();
  }

  Future<Database> database() async {
    return openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'acc_summary_db.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        // Run the CREATE TABLE statement on the database.
        return db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE accounts(accountSummaryCardId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, totalAmount INTEGER, pendingAmount INTEGER, phoneNo INTEGER, place TEXT)",
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
  }

  Future<int> insertACC(AccountSummary accountSummary) async {
    int _accountSummaryCardId = 0;
    Database _db = await database();
    await _db
        .insert('accounts', accountSummary.toMap(),
            conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace)
        .then((value) {
      _accountSummaryCardId = value;
    });

    return _accountSummaryCardId;
  }

  Future<List<AccountSummary>> getAccounts() async {
    Database _db = await database();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> accountMap = await _db.query('accounts');
    return List.generate(
      accountMap.length,
      (index) => AccountSummary(
          accountSummaryCardId: accountMap[index]['accountSummaryCardId'],
          name: accountMap[index]['name'],
          totalAmount: accountMap[index]['totalAmount'],
          pendingAmount: accountMap[index]['pendingAmount'],
          phoneNo: accountMap[index]['phoneNo'],
          place: accountMap[index]['place']),
    );
  }

  Future<void> updateName(int accountSummaryCardId, String name) async {
    Database _db = await database();
    await _db.rawUpdate(
        "UPDATE accounts SET name = '$name' WHERE accountSummaryCardId = '$accountSummaryCardId'");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have the SQLite side managed, but I would suggest you use a state management package like Provider to reduce queries for the data as you will be using this data on multiple screens. Below is an example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return MultiProvider(
   providers:[
    //Simply add your database queries in here
    FutureProvider.value(YOUR_DATABASE_QUERY)
   ]
   child:MaterialApp(...)
  );
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a FutureBuilder:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: YOUR_DATABASE_QUERY,
    builder: (context,snapshot){...}
  );
}
```

Let me know if that fixes your problem and if I understood your question correctly. :)